# help in multiplying values in Two Fields & display in 3rd Field in trigger

Tags: trigger, account

help in multiplying values in Two Fields & display in 3rd Field
Request help in multiplying values in Two  Fields (UnitPrice__c  & QuantitySold__c}

& display the value in edit mode in 3rd Field (TotalSale__c)

All the 03 Fields are  Number type

Comment: What does your trigger look like now, and what kind of result are you getting?

Comment: trigger is tofind total price of a product ? its on insert and update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TotalSale__c` was a [formula field](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas) then this would be much easier to implement.

Here is some sample code to achieve what you are looking for using a trigger. I have left out the logic that checks to see if `UnitPrice__c` or `QuantitySold__c` have changed, which would stop this logic from firing every time any field on your object changed.

```
trigger totalSales on Account(before insert, before update) {
    for (Account a : trigger.new) { 
        // TODO Should only execute if UnitPrice__c or QuantitySold__c have changed 
        if (a.UnitPrice__c != null && a.QuantitySold__c != null) {
            a.TotalSale__c = a.UnitPrice__c * a.QuantitySold__c;
        } else {
            a.TotalSale__c = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the trigger,Please replace trigger name and object name

trigger triggername on objectname(before insert, before upadte){

for(objectname o: trigger.new){
  o.TotalSale__c =o.UnitPrice__c * o.QuantitySold__c;

}

}
Thanks,
Raviteja